# "setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" for a ImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have a app in which I am programaticly creating a ImageView. When I try to create this I get the error:

```
    2013-12-23 21:22:13.674 MagnetFall[22343:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<GameScreenViewController 0xa98eae0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundImage.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019695e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016ec8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x019f96a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x013ad9ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x01319cfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x01319253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0137b70a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x006fca15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016fe7d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01964b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x006fb56e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x0056d605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    12  UIKit                               0x0056ddad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    13  UIKit                               0x0056e0ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    14  UIKit                               0x0056e5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x0057dab9 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
    16  UIKit                               0x0057de01 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 297
    17  UIKit                               0x008025e5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
    18  UIKit                               0x0057a0fc -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6433
    19  UIKit                               0x0057a61f -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    20  UIKit                               0x0057a65f -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
    21  UIKit                               0x0099ee16 -[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
    22  UIKit                               0x0098f07e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    23  UIKit                               0x0098f0f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    24  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016fe874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    25  UIKit                               0x0045c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    26  UIKit                               0x0045c04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    27  UIKit                               0x005540c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    28  UIKit                               0x00554484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    29  UIKit                               0x00553733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    30  UIKit                               0x0049951d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    31  UIKit                               0x0049a184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    32  UIKit                               0x0046de86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    33  UIKit                               0x0045818f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x018f283f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x018f21cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0190f29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0190eac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0190e8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x02f1a9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x02f1a809 GSEventRun + 104
    41  UIKit                               0x0045ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    42  MagnetFall                          0x000052dd main + 141
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x03afe70d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is the code for adding the Image View:

```
UIImageView *background;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    {   //Loads the Background.
        background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundAll.png"]];
        background.center = CGPointMake(160, 284);
        [self.view addSubview:background];

    }
```

Try as I might, I have not figured out a solution. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your xib file and disconnect backgroundImage in File's owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error is nothing to do with the background. It seems something wrong with your xib file.
Does your xib file contains something named as backgroundImage?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access some view from your xib but you have not created its outlet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, check if your doing anything with backgroundImage iVar.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I found that I had accidentally added a connection that was not wired up at all:

[image]